# Is there any trick to use a variable that is read early, in a switch case statement?

Tags: c, switch-statement

I'm working on a practice question that our teacher has given us and it calculates the roots of a quadratic equation. We are said not to use if in it and to use switch_case instead. in this code, I'm asking the user to enter three integer values and after some math operation, the result is the delta that needs to be defined that if it is positive, negative or equal to 0 and then do the appropriate operation on it. like below:

```
int opt=0,a,b,c,delta;
double x1,x2,real,img;
printf("Enter the integer coefficients a, b and c respectively: ");
scanf("%i%i%i",&a,&b,&c);
delta = b*b - 4*a*c;
```

now to link the correct operation to delta's sign, I need to use switch_case like this:

```
switch(delta){
    case delta>0:
        x1=(-b+sqrt(delta))/(2*a);
        x2=(-b-sqrt(delta))/(2*a);
        printf("the roots of the quadratic equation you entered are x1=%.3lf & x2=%.3lf",x1,x2);
    break;
    case 0:
        x1=(-b)/(2*a);
        printf("the roots of the quadratic equation you entered are the same and equal to x=%.3lf",x1);
    break;
    case delta<0:
        real=(-b)/(2*a);
        img=sqrt(-delta)/(2*a);
        printf("the roots of the quadratic equation you entered is x1=%.3lf+i%.3lf & x2=%.3lf-i%.3lf",real,img,real,img);
    break;
    default:
        printf("an error accured during operation");
}
```

but since the delta is not predfined and is being calculated during the execution of the code, the cases don't work and I face with the error "case label does not reduce to an integer constant"
Is there any trick or regular way to use switch_case with such variables(not predefined)??

Comment: The real problem is that you can't just do stuff like this `case delta<0:`.

Comment: The `case` value must be well defined at compile time. Sometimes the compiler builds a jump table to handle the execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`switch` statement allows only the use of integer constants, so your solution can't work.

But considering that a logical operation will give an integer with values 1 or 0 for true and false respectively, you can try:

```
switch (delta > 0)
{
    case 1:
        x1 = (-b + sqrt(delta)) / (2 * a);
        x2 = (-b - sqrt(delta)) / (2 * a);
        printf("the roots of the quadratic equation you entered are x1=%.3lf & x2=%.3lf", x1, x2);
        break;
    case 0:
        switch (delta == 0)
        {
            case 1:
                x1 = (-b) / (2 * a);
                printf("the roots of the quadratic equation you entered are the same and equal to x=%.3lf", x1);
                break;
            case 0: //delta < 0
                real = (-b) / (2 * a);
                img = sqrt(-delta) / (2 * a);
                printf("the roots of the quadratic equation you entered is x1=%.3lf+i%.3lf & x2=%.3lf-i%.3lf", real, img, real, img);
                break;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try the following:

```
int sign = (0 < delta) - (0 > delta);
switch(sign)
{
  case -1: /* 0 > delta */
    ...

    break;

  case 0: /* 0 = delta */
    ...

    break;

  case 1: /* 0 < delta */
    ...

    break;

  default:
    /* Should never arrive here. */
}
```

Comment: Thats pretty clever! My idea was just to use ternary like `0 < delta ? 1 : 0 == delta ? 0 : -1`

Comment: @Eraklon: This conditional expression (aka Ternary operator) I'd consider as an implicit use of if-then.